# How can I write Makefile (with sub Makfile ) more concise

Tags: c, makefile

When I do practice , I have a practice path.

Under this path , I have an Include path named `myInclude` (I have some useful function is this folder and I always use it.)

And a code path named `symbol_try`.I always make add new folder (with a c file and main function in it) in `symbol_try` and compile it.

Each time I have to compile it by gcc in terminal .Its a boring work , so I write a Makefile.

Here is an example:

the main Makefile  in practice path:

```
FOBJS=
include myInclude/Rule.mk
include symbol_try/codeList_13.1/Rule.mk
symbol:$(FOBJS)                   <==What exactly I what . A executable file.
    gcc -o symbol $(FOBJS) -pthread -lpthread

subsystem:
    cd myInclude/ && $(MAKE)
    cd symbol_try/codeList_13.1/ &&$(MAKE)
clean:
    rm -rf symbol
```

In the myInclude/Rule.mk

```
FOBJS+=myInclude/otherFunction.o myInclude/error.o \
       myInclude/unit.o myInclude/unitTest.o\
```

In the symbol_try/codeList_13.1/Rule.mk

```
FOBJS+=symbol_try/codeList_13.1/codeList_13.1.o
```

In myInclude/Makefile:

```
    OBJS=otherFunction.o error.o unit.o unitTest.o
    ALL:$(OBJS)
    .PHONY:ALL
    $(OBJS):%.o:%.c
        gcc -c $< -o $@

    clean :
        otherFunction.o error.o unit.o
```

In symbol_try/codeList_13.1/Makefile:

```
codeList_13.1.o:codeList_13.1.c
    gcc -c codeList_13.1.c
```

Well.That can work. But as you see , I have to write a Rule.mk(to initialize the FOBJS) and a Makefile for each folder.

I am new for make , I want find a way more  concise , witch I only need write one Makefile for each folder and a main Makefile.**No Rule.mk any more**.

PS: I always change the code in myInclude ,so I don't want to build it a library.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you can do it with just one Makefile:

```
CC        = gcc
CPPFLAGS += -I myInclude/                             (1)
CFLAGS   += -std=c99 -Wall                            (2)
VPATH     = myInclude/ \                              (3)
            symbol_try/codeList_13.1/

symbol: otherFunction.o error.o unit.o unitTest.o codeList_13.1.o  (4)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^                                    (5)

.PHONY : clean
clean:
    rm -f symbol *.o
```

Note that `make` knows how to build C files and has some standard macros: CC, CPPFLGAS, CFLAGS

1. Add the include paths of your headers.  You presumably have some headers for the individual object files in the `myInclude` directory.
2. Put the compiler flags here.
3. Add the paths to the source files you want to build.
4. List the object files that the executable depends upon
5. As there is no file called `symbol.c` you need to tell make how to create `symbol.o` with a rule. `$@` means the target ('symbol', here), and `$^` means all of the prerequisites (the object files listed).

Here's a list of all of the files in my test directories for this:

```
$ find . -type f
.
./Makefile
./myInclude/error.c
./myInclude/header.h
./myInclude/otherFunction.c
./myInclude/unit.c
./myInclude/unitTest.c
./symbol_try/codeList_13.1/codeList_13.1.c
```

And the build output:

```
$ make
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -I myInclude/  -c -o otherFunction.o myInclude/otherFunction.c
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -I myInclude/  -c -o error.o myInclude/error.c
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -I myInclude/  -c -o unit.o myInclude/unit.c
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -I myInclude/  -c -o unitTest.o myInclude/unitTest.c
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -I myInclude/  -c -o codeList_13.1.o symbol_try/codeList_13.1/codeList_13.1.c
gcc -o symbol otherFunction.o error.o unit.o unitTest.o codeList_13.1.o
```

Comment: After add **CFLAGS   += -std=c99 -Wall** something just goes wrong .Some struct and marco didn't work . I remove that line, everthing turn ok, why this happened?

Comment: You can remove both of these (ie. just have `CFLAGS += `) if you want.  But `-Wall` is best kept to check for mistakes in the code. `-Wall` turns on the normal gcc warnings, which can cause a lot of messages if your code is incorrect.  The `-std=c99` decides which flavour of C the compiler will use. There are other settings, see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a library from the objects in myInclude and do the linking in the Makefile in your code path (symbol_try/codeList_13.1). The latter is better anyway because the needed libraries (`-pthread -lpthread` in your case) might change as well for some other code. 
The main Makefile now would have got nothing to do but call make in all needed subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

In each folder have a makefile with

```
    SOURCES=sample.c sampletest.c

    OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)

    all: $(OBJECTS)

    $(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

In the root directory of a project, create a makefile with a rule to compile every sub-folder like the below.

```
    Dirs= path-to-rootdir
    objs:
    set -e ; \
    for i in $(Dirs) ; do \
      $(MAKE) CC="$(CC)" CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS_MODULE)" LDFLAGS="$(LDFLAGS)"  OBJDIR="$(OBJDIR)" -C $$i; \
done
```

And then you could use it build the executable by adding a rule

```
   EXE: objs
    $(CC)  -L./Path1 $(LIB_PATH)  -llib1  -o $(EXE_NAME) $(wildcard $(OBJDIR)/*.o)
```

Hope this helps!!!